# Is there a closed form for  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax^2}}{\mathrm{erfc}{(-bx)}} dx$?

Tags: integration, special-functions

The integral expression is 
$$    
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax^2}}{\mathrm{erfc}{(-bx)}} dx
$$
where $a>0$ and $b>0$.

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral most likely does not admit a closed form in terms of known special functions.

Using
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-a x^2} \frac{ \mathrm{d} x}{\operatorname{erfc}(-b x)}   &=&  
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{(b^2-a) x^2} \mathrm{d} \left(\log (\operatorname{erfc}(-b x))  \right) \\ &=& \left. \mathrm{e}^{(b^2-a) x^2} \log (\operatorname{erfc}(-b x)) \right|_{x \downarrow -\infty}^{x \uparrow +\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^\infty 2 x (b^2-a) \mathrm{e}^{(b^2-a) x^2} \log (\operatorname{erfc}(-b x)) \mathrm{d} x
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Since $\log (\operatorname{erfc}(-b x))$ is at [most polynomial growth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45694/mills-ratio-for-gaussian-q-function), it follows that convergence requires $a > b^2$.

Indeed, here is a plot of the integrand for $b=1$ and $a = \frac{1}{2}$:

[image]