# upper and lower bounds of $E[X|X>x]$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

I am trying to find tight upper and lower bounds for $E[X | X > x]$ where $X$ follows a standard normal random variable. After calculations I found that
$$ E [X|X>x] = \frac{\exp(-x^2/2)}{\int_{x}^{\infty} \exp(-u^2/2) du} $$

When I plot this in R, I find that this is just a line. So how can I simplify the above expression and find a closed solution of it? Or can I get tight bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answers the original formulation of the queston**, which was to find tight lower and upper bounds for $\mathrm{E}(X\mid X>0)$.

The expectation $\mathrm{E}\left(X \mid X>0\right)$ can be computed in closed form as follows:
$$
   \mathrm{E}\left(X \mid X>0\right) = \frac{\int_0^\infty x \phi(x) \mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^\infty \phi(x) \mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\int_0^\infty x \phi(x) \mathrm{d}x}{1/2} = \int_0^\infty 2 x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) \mathrm{d}x
$$
Making a change of variables $u = \frac{x^2}{2}$ 
$$
  \mathrm{E}\left(X \mid X>0\right) = \int_0^\infty \frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp(-u) \mathrm{d}u = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} 
$$
This is as tight as it gets.

---

The updated question can be solved by the technique from my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632825) to an earlier question. Let $Z$ be a Gaussian random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$. Then
$$
   \mathrm{E}\left(X \mid X > x\right) = x + \mathrm{E}\left(X-x \mid X -x > 0\right) = x + \mathrm{E}\left(Z \mid Z > 0\right)
$$
where $\mu = -x$ and $\sigma=1$. Now using an easily verified identity
$$
   \sigma^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} f_Z(z; \mu, \sigma) + \mu f_Z(z; \mu, \sigma) = z f_Z(z; \mu, \sigma)
$$
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \mathrm{E}\left(Z \mathbf{1}_{Z > 0}\right) &=& \int_0^\infty z f_Z(z) \mathrm{d} z = \mu  \Pr(Z>0) + \sigma^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \Pr(Z>0) \\ &=& \mu \Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) +  \sigma^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) \\ &=& \mu \Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)  + \sigma \phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Hence
$$
   \mathrm{E}(X \mid X > 0) = x + \frac{\mathrm{E}\left(Z \mathbf{1}_{Z > 0}\right)}{\Pr(Z>0)} = x + \mu + \sigma \frac{\phi\left(\mu/\sigma\right)}{\Phi\left(\mu/\sigma\right)} 
$$
now recalling $\mu = -x$ and $\sigma=1$, and $\phi(-x) = \phi(x)$
$$
\mathrm{E}(X \mid X > 0) = \frac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(-x)}
$$
which is precisely what you found.

This function is known as [inverse Mill's ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Mills_ratio) and is not a linear function, but approaches linear function for large positive $x$:

[image]

Comment: I am really sorry, I wanted to write x, but instead I wrote 0. Can you solve it for general x? I will edit the question. Again sorry for the confusion

Comment: @neticin Please see my updated post.